# Ways to alias a function from another source file?

Tags: c

I need a function from one source file to have the same functionality but a different name in another source file.

I have identified some options and some of their drawbacks:

- wrapping function - added function call unless it is optimized by the compiler
- macro alias - using small letters is more logical and aesthetic, but would result in an inconsistency because it is common to make all macros (even function macros) capital so they are identifiable
- inline - I am unsure if you can inline a function from another source file

What would be the optimal solution?

What would be the optimal solution?

Comment: "Optimal" measured how?

Comment: Seems to be much the same question as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75843857/kernel-standard-of-wrapping-functions-that-do-not-need-any-changes-while-making). Why did you make a new user? Also, questions asking for an opinion are likely to be closed and deleted pretty quickly.

Comment: This suggests the "other" file's function name has been made too specific (tied to other function names in the same file.) Rename that function to indicate its purpose and use that (generic?) name in all your source files.

Comment: Re “inconsistency because it is common”: Using a different practice than is common is not an inconsistency. Do not be bound by decades old conventions. Using all uppercase is distracting, and the purposes of the convention created decades ago is less useful now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Declare the function with its original name and make a pointer with the new name:

```
extern void b(void);
static void (* const a)(void) = b;
```

In GCC or Clang, use an extension to use a different name in the object module than is used in source code:

```
extern void a(void) __asm__("_b");
```

(`b` or `_b` might be needed for the object name depending on the build target.)